# UIWebview crashing when open pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an app built with Objective C which is crashing only on iOS 16. iOS 15 & below is working fine.

I am simply opening pdf link in the webview. Below is the code I am using.

```
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myUrlAsString]];
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

`myUrlAsString` is holding the url of the pdf.

When I check further I found it's crashing with my pdf only. But question is this is working with iOS 15.

Before I had log saying *CoreGraphics PDF has logged an error. Set environment variable "CG_PDF_VERBOSE" to learn more.*, so I set CG_PDF_VERBOSE as 1 & I get below in logs.

Replacing TrueType font `Arial,Bold' with` Arial-BoldMT'.
Replacing TrueType font `Arial,BoldItalic' with` Arial-BoldItalicMT'.

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

Same is happening with Books app of Apple. Which means this is bug from Apple.

Comment: `UIWebView` is deprecated since iOS 12. You should consider migrating to `WKWebView`.

Comment: @fahim Have you found a solution yet? If so could you post it

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif no. this is issue from Apple side I think. Even Books app is crashing...